# How to solve $i^z = \ln z$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

How to solve $i^z = \ln z$?

Putting $z = re^{i\theta}$ and $i = e^{i\pi/2}$ gives : 
$$
e^{i\pi/2re^{i\theta}}= \ln r +i\pi 
$$

How to continue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and equate the real and imaginary parts of both sides of the equation you've obtained to get the equations \begin{eqnarray}
%\begin{split}
e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}r\sin\theta}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}r\cos\theta\right)=&\ln r \\
\ e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}r\sin\theta}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}r\cos\theta\right)=&\pi 
%\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
From these equations you'll get $$\cos\theta=\frac{2}{\pi r}\arctan\left(\frac{\ln r}{\pi}\right)$$

Use this in any one of the previous two equations to eliminate $\theta$ and get an equation only in $r$. Of course it will be a messy transcendental equation in $r$. You can numerically solve for $r$ and then use the last equation to get $\theta$.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+exp%28-pi%2F2%2ar%2a%5Csqrt%7B1-4%2F%28pi%5E2%2ar%5E2%29%2a%28arctan%28%5Cln%28r%29%2Fpi%29%29%5E2%7D%29%2F%5Csqrt%7B1%2B%28%5Cln%28r%29%2Fpi%29%5E2%7D%3D%5Cln%28r%29) gives the solution $r=1.17187209744601...$ and from that we get $\theta \approx 88.429765^{\circ}$

Comment: There must be something wrong in this answer:

Comment: $$i^{1.17187209744601 e^{i 88.429765^ \circ}}=0.15860256 +
0.0080069382i\\ \log(1.17187209744601 e^{i 88.429765^ \circ})=0.15860255 +1.5433906 i$$